# An $\mathcal{L}^1$ optimization problem in function space

Tags: optimization, functional-calculus, variational-analysis

Let $f: (-\infty,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a smooth map. Then, how to solve the following optimizatin problem w.r.t. $f$?

\begin{align}
\mathrm{minimize}_f&~~\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x) - \exp(-x^2)| dx\\
s.t.&~~\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 f(x) = 1
\end{align}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution. To see this, use the Lagrange multiplier's theorem [infinite dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multipliers_on_Banach_spaces) in the space of integrable functions to find critical points of
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\vert f(x)-e^{-x^{2}}\right\vert \,dx+\lambda
\left(  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}f(x)\,dx-1\right)  .
$$
Now the function $e^{-x^{2}}$ satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}
e^{-x^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$ so it is not a solution. Hence, the
solution $f$ cannot always be equal to $f$. Consider the set $\left\{
x:\,f(x)>e^{-x^{2}}\right\}  $. Since this set is open, we can write it as a
union of intervals. Let $(a,b)$ be one of these intervals and let $g\in
C_{c}((a,b))$. Then for $t>0$ small enough we have that $f(x)+tg(x)>e^{-x^{2}
}$ in $(a,b)$. Consider the function$$
F(t)=\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)+tg(x)-e^{-x^{2}})\,dx+\lambda\left(  \int_{a}^{b}
x^{2}(f(x)+tg(x))\,dx-1\right)  .
$$
We must have $F^{\prime}(0)=0$, that is,$$
0=\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx+\lambda\int_{a}^{b}x^{2}g(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^{b}(1+\lambda
x^{2})g(x)\,dx.
$$
Since this is true for every $g$ it follows that $1+\lambda x^{2}=0$ for all
$x\in(a,b)$, which is impossible.

I think that there should be a simpler way to prove this.

**Edit**
To see why we can apply the Lagrange multiplier theorem in $(a,b)$, assume that $f$ is a solution of the original problem, with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}f(x)\,dx=1$ and let $[a,b]$ be such that $f(x)-e^{-x^2}>$ in $[a,b]$ (so I am taking $(a,b)$ a bit smaller than above). Then $f(x)-e^{-x^2}\ge\delta/(b-a)>0$ in $[a,b]$ for some $\delta$.  Let $m=\int_{a}^{b}x^2 f(x)\,dx$. Consider $g\in
C_c((a,b))$ with $\Vert g\Vert_{C([a,b])}\le\delta$ and $\int_a^b x^2g(x)\,dx=0$. Extend $g$ to be zero outside $(a,b)$. Then the function $f+g$ satisfies the constraint $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2}(f(x)+g(x))\,dx=1$ and so 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\vert (f(x)+g(x))-e^{-x^{2}}\right\vert \,dx\ge \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\vert f(x)-e^{-x^{2}}\right\vert \,dx,$$ which implies that
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left((f(x)+g(x))-e^{-x^{2}}\right) \,dx\ge \int_{a}^{b}\left( f(x)-e^{-x^{2}}\right) \,dx.$$
This implies that $f$ is a constrained minimizer of the functional
$$H(h):=\int_{a}^{b}\left(h(x)-e^{-x^{2}}\right) \,dx$$
over all $h$ in the open ball of 
$C_0((a,b))$ centered at $f$ and radius $\delta$, subject to the constraint $\int_{a}^{b}x^2 h(x)\,dx=m$. We can now apply the Lagrange multiplier theorem as above to get a contradiction.

Comment: Thank very much for your detailed answer! [+1] Does it mean the objective function is not lower bounded? But it should have a lower bound $0$.

Comment: I am not sure if $F'(0) = 0$ can be applied. This problem seems to be related to the Pontryagin's maximum principle, where the Hamiltonian should be minimized (i.e., $F'(0)$ can be non-zero). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin's_maximum_principle

Comment: No the infimum is a number $0\le \ell=\inf_f
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\vert f(x)-e^{-x^{2}}\right\vert \,dx$ but it is not attained. There is no function $f$ such that $
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left\vert f(x)-e^{-x^{2}}\right\vert \,dx=\ell$

Comment: If you have a minimizer, then $F(t)\ge F(0)$ for all $t$ small. This implies that $F'(0)=0$. It's a result for functions of one variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that if we want to make $F'(0) \to 0$, the interval $(a,b)$ must be an infinitesimal. In my opinion, $\lambda$ should be close to $-1/a^2 \approx -1/b^2$ in that case, and I think: 1. $F'(0) \to 0$ cannot provide sufficient information of optimal solution (since it is a necessary condition); or 2. The optimal solution is not a continuous function (probably having infinite number of jumps), where means $f^*$ does not exist in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Sorry, I got a typo in the last comment, and the correct statement is "The interval length $b-a$ must be an infinitesimal".

Comment: @Gio67 I don't think you can use $F'(0)=0$ here. The Lagrange multiplier theorem is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition. When you put $F'(0)=0$ there, you are finding $\bar{t}$ such that:

Comment: $\bar{t}$ solves $$min \int_a^b (f(x)+tg(x )- e^{-x^2})dx, \; \;s.t \int_a^b(x^2(f(x)+tg(x)))dx=1.$$ This last constraint it is not related to the problem at all. Hence my statement

Comment: Yes, you can. If  we assume that $f$ is a solution of the original problem, then it will also be a solution of the same problem in $(a,b)$ subject to $\int_a^bx^2f(x)\,dx=c>0$. Hence, you can use the Lagrange multiplier there.

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: In your proof, who is $C_c((a,b))$? How do you guarantee that $f+tg$ is smooth?

Comment: I will upvote as soon as I understand your proof. Just clarify those details

Comment: $C_c((a,b))$ is the space of continuous functions with compact support. You could also take $C_c^1((a,b))$, continuous functions with continuous derivative and with compact support.